# Drop down list in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

i need help to solve my problem. I can't make my selector to display 92 times , i wrote FOR instruction for this but it only display one selector with the value form Database , how can i do this...
My code:

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","sergios.com");
    if (!$con)
       {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("phptests", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category");

 for($i=1;$i<92;++$i){  
  echo "<select>";
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    echo "<option>" .  $line['name'] . "</option>";
     }
      echo "</select>"; 
      }

  ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Do you mean that you have 92 values, but that the same value is being displayed in all 92 options? Or is your issue that you want exactly 92 options displayed, but you sometimes have more?

Comment: Do you really mean that you know you have 92 Categories in your db, and want to display them all in the same, single droplist?

Comment: @SergiuBugneac: It's great that you know. Now implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need 92 select boxes needs to be displayed. Try with the following code....

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category"); 
$options = "";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $options .= "<option>" .  $line['name'] . "</option>";
}
for($i=1;$i<92;++$i){ 
    echo "<select>";
    echo $options;
    echo "</select>"; 
}
```

Comment: Will this code not run 92 seperate queries? Seems very innefficient.

Comment: 92 queries for the same stuff? urgh.

Comment: i can't find it , it's my first question , could you tell me

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the opening and closing select outside of the loop. As you are already looping thrue the results, you do not need a extra for loop:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","sergios.com");
if (!$con)  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("phptests", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category");

echo "<select>";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  echo "<option>" .  $line['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: i still not clear, can u write the full code please :), i will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct the options outside the for loop

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category"); 
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{ 
    $myOptions .= "<option>" .  $line['name'] . "</option>"; 
} 
for($i=1;$i<92;++$i){   
  echo "<select>"; 
     echo $myOptions;    
  echo "</select>";  
}
```

Comment: What is the point in putting 92 exact the same selects on the screen?

Comment: I don't really know.. I've used something like this for attaching store products to newsletters.. Is true that I've used just 10 products.. not 92..

Comment: mihai salut, la mine e un proiect in care trebuie sa am coloana cu 92 de selectori pentru a putea rapid de schimbat mai multe chestiuni din proiect =]